# Merging changes from base repository to a fork

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge, tortoisehg

Let's say we have a base repository R and a fork F. Coders are still making changes in R and F needs to include these changes as they are being added.

How do I tell hg to update F with the latest changes in R without losing the work I am doing on F?

Using the diff tool is a heck of a time-consuming task and it is not helping me move forward.

I am using TortoiseHG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware of `merge`? If you are and your issue is merge conflicts, then your diff tool is how you'll need to proceed.

The way to do this, assuming you are working locally on F and that the tip of F is your current working directory:

- ... commit all work in F ...
- Pull new changesets from R
- Right click the tip of the work in R and select "Merge with local"
- fill in your commit message "merge in xyz from R"
- ... do more work in F...

That's it. If the changes in R and F don't overlap, you should be done and ready to move on. If work in R and F both modify the same parts of the same files, you'll need to use your diff tool to resolve those merge conflicts.